# How can I downgrade Bash?

Tags: bash, downgrade

Im trying to implement Shellshock and I need downgrade Bash to a vuln. version. I don't know how get it and there isn't much information in the Internet about it.

I'm working with Ubuntu Server 14.04.

How I can get it?

Comment: Which distro do you use? I think you can get a specific version of bash via your packaging tool

Comment: The answer to this depends entirely on your OS. In any case, I would suggest that this question is off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm forget write it. I'm working with Ubuntu Server 14.04. Bash version=4.3.11. @polym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't downgrade the system bash. That's a terrible idea. Get the source for a vulnerable version and compile it yourself.

(Don't install it to the system though if you can avoid it, just run it from the source directory.)

Comment: Thanks, I did this and works fine. Thank you for your time Etan ! :)